Errors upgrading Microsoft.Graph NuGet package to version 5.54 in .NET 8
I'm trying to upgrade the Microsoft.Graph NuGet package from version 4.24 to version 5.54 in my .NET 8 project. After the upgrade, I'm encountering errors in my code.I attached screen shot and sample code below.
 var graphResponse = await GetGraphServiceClient().Users[FromAddress]
                .SendMail(email, true)
                .Request()
                .PostResponseAsync();

  email.Attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
  foreach (var urlAttachment in emailMessage.URLAttachments)
  {
      var attachment = new FileAttachment();
      attachment.ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment";
      email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
  }


How can I resolve the error for MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage?
How should I modify the SendMail method call to fix the CS1955 error?

From what version did you upgrade?

Seems like you are using code from SDK v4.

can this section help to solve your issue? it provides a sample for send email with attachments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-2

upgraded from version 4.24 to version 5.54

Could you pls let me know whether the sample from the link helped or not?
